# PHP-PDO Search query then update the result

Tags: php, pdo

Guys please see my code below. I really have no idea how to run my query. what I want to achieve are I will first search in my database the DATA **which is not yet finished or cancelled** then the returned data will be updated the over due fields to NO.
 I run correctly the first query which is the searching. But I dont know how to make the second. please help. thanks.

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

class updateOverdue{
    private $db,$sql,$stmt,$row;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();

    }
    public function updatefields(){
        $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM jrf_tbl WHERE status <> 'Finished' AND status <> 'Cancelled'";
        $this->stmt = $this->db->prepare($this->sql);
        $this->stmt->execute();

            if($this->stmt->rowCount()){
                while($this->row = $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                 echo "
                        <tbody>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>",$TEST= $this->row->ID, "</td> 
                                <td>",$this->row->strjrfnum, "</td>
                                <td>",$this->row->strstatus,"</td>
                                <td>",$this->row->strpriority,"</td>
                                <td>",$this->row->strdate,"</td>
                                <td>",$this->row->strduedate,"</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>";
                  }
            };

            foreach ($TEST as $value) { /* here is my question */
                $this->sql = "UPDATE jrf_tbl SET strifoverdue ='no' WHERE ID=". $value;
                $this->stmt = $this->db->prepare($this->sql);
                $this->stmt->execute();
            }
        }

}//End Class

?>

    <table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>JRF Num</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Date received</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php 
            $OverDue = new updateOverdue();
            $OverDue->updatefields();
        ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single query:

```
UPDATE jrf_tbl SET strifoverdue ='no'
    WHERE status <> 'Finished' AND status <> 'Cancelled'"
```

And btw your `$TEST` variable is not an array so you can't loop through it. It just contains the last value from the query.

Yes it will not give you any result because it just updates the database.

But if you really want to display all the affected rows, your initial approach is ok but when it comes to the update query you're better off using `WHERE IN` instead of looping and doing a single update on each iteration since you already have all the ID's in your `$TEST` variable

Comment: OH GOD!! im thinking a lot i miss the simplest things. thank you! my bad im so newbie =_=.  ahmm do you know or do you have any reference. regarding, i want to update all data which is over their due.?

Comment: its like UPDATE jrf_tbl SET strifoverdue ='no'
    WHERE status <> 'Finished' AND status <> 'Cancelled' AND  overdue_date > date_now"  is this working? cause i have no result

Answer (score 1):

$TEST contains id

```
$TEST= $this->row->ID
```

But you expecting, what $TEST is array

```
foreach ($TEST as $value)
```

And i think, better way is to write you update query like this:

```
UPDATE jrf_tbl SET strifoverdue ='no' 
WHERE status <> 'Finished' AND status <> 'Cancelled'
```